# How to successfully load data of a particular user or event into bootstrap modal in laravel using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to load Event data into my bootstrap modal in laravel but it isn't working for me as i just started using ajax. Please check out what i did

**Modal template**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="readmore" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Event Title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <!-- Read More Event-->
      
      <div class="content">
        <form>
@csrf
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="" value="{!! $edit_event-> title !!}" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="" value="{!! $edit_event-> deadline !!}" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control">{{$edit_event-> message}}</textarea>
          </div>

        </form>
        
      </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Button**

```
<button data-toggle="modal" title="Edit" class="eventinfo" data-id="{{ $msg->id }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</button>
```

**Ajax or Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".eventinfo").click(function(){
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            var token = $(this).data("token");
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/event/edit/"+id,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {
                    "id": id,
                    "_method": 'POST',
                    "_token": token,
                },
                success: function (response)
                {
                    $('.modal-body').html(response);
                    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');

                }
            });

            console.log("It failed");
            alert('failed');
        });

</script>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/event/edit/{id}', 'EventController@edit');
```

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id){
            $edit_event = Event::findOrfail($id);

            if ($new_event) {
                return response()->json(['edit_event'=> $edit_event,
            ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['status'=> 'error']);
            }



       }
```

Please any help about how to go about it? i want to load the data into a bootstrap modal using Laravel. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's quite some stuff going wrong in your code:

- You're vulnerable to cross site scripting as soon as you use `{!! $someVar !!}`. So try to avoid it at any case. There's also the `@json` helper available, which you cna use like `<span id='@json($myId)'>`. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade for more info.
- Your controller is returning status `200` for both success and error cases. This is an anti-pattern for any API. The `$new_event` param in your controller is also missing (it is undefined).
- You can simplify your jQuery AJAX calls by adding an automatic `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Add CSRF token header on every ajax request.
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
});
```

In your root template, then simply add `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in your `<head>` and the `$.ajaxSetup` function should automatically add the correct CSRF token for you on each ajax request. The HTTP header `X-CSRF-TOKEN` is automatically recognized by Laravel (it has the same function as sending a `_token` parameter in a POST request body).

- Your `alert('failed');` line will always be called, there is no `return` statement nor are you placing it in any sort of failure-callback.
- A possible bug is being introduced in your ajax `success` callback, since you are setting `$('.modal-body')` content which will set the content for ALL elements that have this class.

I suggest you start debugging your javascript function and see if your click handler is being called. Also check your browsers' network tab to see if the ajax request is properly executed.